# Nuxt how to loop on an array and display the data properly with a v-for

Tags: json, vue.js, nuxt.js

I have an e-commerce site, I want to loop the nested data from json. I tried many things but couldn't find.

```
async fetch() {
    this.post = await fetch(
      `http://test.com/api.php?id=${this.$route.params.id}`
    ).then((res) => res.json())
  }
```

I use like this;

```
<h3>{{ post.title }}</h3>
<li v-for="(index, post.sizes) in sizes" :key="index">
        {{ sizes.index }}
      </li>
```

My json Data is : `"sizes": "[\"XS\",\"S\",\"M\",\"L\"]",`

thanks for helping.

Comment: Hi, I think you need to use it like `v-for="(index, size) in post.sizes"` and then access `{{ size }}`. Also if this does not help then can you share the whole component how you are using it and also the whole jsonData structure.

Comment: I think your code should be something like this `<li v-for="(size, index) in sizes" :key="index"> {{ size }}</li>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Having this kind of code is not really okay.

```html
<li v-for="(size, index) in sizes" :key="index">
  {{ size }}
</li>
```

You need to update your data to something like this

```js
sizes: [
  { id: 1, name: "XS" },
  { id: 2, name: "S" },
  { id: 3, name: "M" },
  { id: 4, name: "L" },
]
```

Or even better, fetch some ids from an API and then, use it like this

```html
<li v-for="size in sizes" :key="side.id">
  {{ size.name }}
</li>
```

Having a mutable `index` is not something that you should use for `:key` since it's does the opposite of what is is supposed to do.

---

`:key` is essential, more info here: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/style-guide/#Keyed-v-for-essential

Here a blog article explaining this: https://michaelnthiessen.com/understanding-the-key-attribute#dont-use-an-index-as-the-key