# How to properly iterate on array of objects in Vue/Nuxt

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>Hello World</h1>
    <div>
      <span :for="day in days">{{ day }} </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'Hello',
  data() {
    return {
      days: ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thurs', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun'],
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

## I am not able to loop through `days` array. I am getting below error.

> Error: [Vue warn]: Property or method "day" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property. See: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a similar question: [Nuxt how to loop on an array and display the data properly with a v-for](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68045735/8816585)

And same as there, I do recommend generating some ids for properly handling of `:key`, otherwise you'll get an ESlint error.

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>Hello World</h1>
    <div>
      <span v-for="day in days" :key="day.id">
        {{ day.name }}
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'Hello',
  data() {
    return {
      days: [
        { id: 1, name: "Mon" },
        { id: 2, name: "Tue" },
        { id: 3, name: "Wed" },
        { id: 4, name: "Thurs" },
        { id: 5, name: "Fri" },
        { id: 6, name: "Sat" },
        { id: 7, name: "Sun" },
      ]
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

`:key` is essential, more info here: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/style-guide/#Keyed-v-for-essential

Here a blog article explaining this: https://michaelnthiessen.com/understanding-the-key-attribute#dont-use-an-index-as-the-key

Answer (score 2):

You should use `v-for` directive like :

```html
<span v-for="day in days">{{ day }}</span>
```

the directives are prefixed by `v-` and they are bound by default to the component methods and properties